# Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Login::loginMenu(void)

Tags: c++, header-files, lnk2019

I searched through the website and there were answers about default constructor or using #pragma. but I'm using #pragma in my visual studio and I tried to debug but any of those methods didnt work. Please tell where I have made the mistake. Thank you

this is my main,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

#include "Login.h"


using namespace std;




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

Login log;
log.loginMenu();


std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

login.h is as following,
    #pragma once

```
class Login
{
public:
void loginMenu();
};
```

and the Login.cpp file,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Login.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


void loginMenu()
{
int userType;

do{

    cout << "Select 1 for STAFF" << endl;
    cout << "Select 2 for HR MANAGER" << endl;
    cout << "Select 3 for ADMINISTRATOR" << endl;

    cout << "Please select your usertype";
    cin >> userType;


    switch(userType){
    case 1:
        cout << "You have selected STAFF";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You have selected HR MANAGER";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You have selected ADMINISTRATOR";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please make your choice by selecting from 1-3";
    }
}while(userType==1,userType==2,userType==3);


}
```

This is a simple program I created to demonstrate "using classes in separate files.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?: Function/variable declared as class member, defined as global (or vice versa)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/902497).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared, and are calling, a function `Login::loginMenu` - a member function of class `Login` - but you haven't implemented it. You have implemented a function `::loginMenu` - a non-member stand-alone function - but you are not calling it.

Make it

```
void Login::loginMenu() {...}
```